# How to install matplotlib on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: django, numpy, amazon-web-services, matplotlib, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Because matplotlib needs numpy to already be installed, I have run into an issue.

To install other python packages on my Elastic Beanstalk environment, I use the pip requirements.txt file. Because the setup configuration automatically installs the packages in alphabetical order, matplotlib always is installed first which causes an error.

Has anyone had this problem and know of a way to successfully fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been beating my head against the wall with this for several days but it seems that if you want to install matplotlib/scipy/scikit-learn using a requirements.txt file you need to do things one module at a time.

What I have been able to understand is that on Elastic Beanstalk packages are not installed in the site-packages directory of the virtual environment until it has successfully worked its way through the entire requirements.txt file.

So for example if you try to install numpy and scipy at the same time, as I was doing, it will fail because scipy cannot find certain numpy modules (numpy.distutils.core specifically).  Numpy is sitting in `/opt/python/run/venv/build` waiting to go but pip is looking in `/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages` and doesn't find numpy.

You need to make one commit with only numpy in your requirements.txt file and push this up to Elastic Beanstalk.  If this succeeds the numpy module will be in the right place and then you can make a second commit with requirements updated to scipy or matplotlib in your case.

Be careful with your configuration file in .ebextensions, you need to have all the dependencies listed.  Specifically, at the top of `.ebextensions/myapp.config` you should have

```
packages:
  yum:
    gcc-c++: []
    gcc-gfortran: []
    python-devel: []
    atlas-sse3-devel: []
    lapack-devel: []
    libpng-devel: []
    freetype-devel: []
    zlib-devel: []
```

`atlas-sse3-devel` and `lapack-devel` are needed if you want scipy and `libpng-devel`, `freetype-devel`, and `zlib-devel` are needed for matplotlib.

The other alternative is to SSH to the ec2 instance associated with your app on Elastic Beanstalk, start up the virtual environment (`source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate`) and pip install the packages yourself.

Comment: Thanks a ton! That was killing me. Your answer got it to work.

Comment: No problem.  If you haven't already done so, my advice would be to create a custom AMI from your working instance so that you can reuse the installation if you shut it down or deploy another branch.

Comment: I am finally back to work on this. Your suggestion was to use a custom AMI. Rather than this, I feel the better way would be to write a script to implement this in my conf file. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Creating a script would be a good thing but it is a little tricky. If you look at the [documentation for a custom environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) it would seem logical to put your script under the Commands heading but these are run "before the application and web server are set up" so I don't think you have access to the virtual env.  The only other alternative is Container_commands but I think these commands are executed after requirements.txt is read so your script has to install numpy/matplotlib after all other modules.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you need to pull all the dependencies out of your requirements.txt file and run them separately in your script to make sure things are done in the right order.

Comment: So right now, I am sticking with your original solution. I have had no  luck writing a script that executes properly. If you ever have any luck with it, let me know

Comment: I came up with a solution for getting scipy onto elastic beanstalk and avoiding the whole finicky process of letting beanstalk install everything.  It involves setting up the virtualenv on the beanstalk EC2, then tarballing it up and re-deploying it via the container_commands section next time you deploy.  So it's kind of a cross between baking a custom AMI and doing everything through custom environment scripting.  It's easier to manipulate and deploy a virtualenv tarball than dealing with baking and re-baking an AMI.

Comment: @Nate: [I can't get this to work.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28099881/656912) I'm trying the simplest of the approaches suggested here (pip in SSH), but not even that works for me.

Comment: @nsecord, i am getting `yum does not have python-devel available for installation`?

Comment: @greenafrican, sorry it was a long time ago and without any information on what OS you are using, it is hard to say.  I believe on CentOS and Redhat, the package is python-devel, on Ubuntu it is python-dev.  Do a search on yum packages with the OS you are using.