# How can I install matplotlib for my AWS Elastic Beanstalk application?

Tags: numpy, amazon-web-services, matplotlib, pip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having a hell of a time deploying matplotlib on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. [I gather](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15881797/656912) that my issue comes from some dependencies and the way that EB deploys packages installed with PIP, and have attempted to follow the [instructions here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15881797/656912) for resolving the issue.

I first tried incrementally deploying, as suggested in the linked answer, by adding pieces of the matplotlib package stack to my `requirements.txt` file in stages. But this takes *forever* (for each stage) and is prone to failure and timing out (which seems to leave build directories behind that stall subsequent package installations).

So the simple solution mentioned off-handedly at the end of the answer appeals to me: just `eb ssh`, activate the virtialenv with

```
source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
```

and `pip install` packages manually. But I can't get this to work either. First I'm often confronted with left-beind build directories (as mentioned above)

```
pip can't proceed with requirement 'xxxx' due to a pre-existing build directory.
 location: /opt/python/run/venv/build/xxxx
This is likely due to a previous installation that failed.
pip is being responsible and not assuming it can delete this.
Please delete it and try again.
```

But even after removing these, I consistently get

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 582, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(temp_location, location, content_type, link)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 625, in unpack_file
    untar_file(filename, location)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/util.py", line 533, in untar_file
    os.makedirs(location)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/python/run/venv/build/xxxx'
```

in response to `pip install xxxx` (and `sudo pip` fails with `sudo: pip: command not found`).

What can I do to get this working on AWS-EB? In particular, what do I need to do to get the simple SSH+PIP approach working; or is there some other better — simpler! — approach I should try.

---

FWIW, I have a `.ebextensions/software.config` with

```
packages:
  yum:
    gcc-c++: []
    gcc-gfortran: []
    python-devel: []
    atlas-sse3-devel: []
    lapack-devel: []
    libpng-devel: []
    freetype-devel: []
    zlib-devel: []
```

and a `requirements.txt` that ends with

```
pytz==2014.10
pyparsing==2.0.3
python-dateutil==2.4.0
nose==1.3.4
six>=1.8.0
mock==1.0.1

numpy==1.9.1

matplotlib==1.4.2
```

After about 4 hours, I've gotten far as numpy (as reported by `pip list` in the EB virtualenv).

And (in case it matters) the user who is SSHing is part in a group with the policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "elasticbeanstalk:*",
        "ec2:*",
        "elasticloadbalancing:*",
        "autoscaling:*",
        "cloudwatch:*",
        "s3:*",
        "sns:*",
        "cloudformation:*",
        "rds:*",
        "sqs:*",
        "iam:PassRole"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used many approaches to build and deploy numpy/scipy/matplotlib, on Windows as well as Linux systems. I have used system-provided package managers (aptitude, rpm), 3rd-party package managers (pypm), Python package managers (easy_install, pip), source releases, used different build environments/tools (GCC, but also Intel MKL, OpenMP). While doing so, I have run into many many quite annoying situations, but have also learned a lot about the pros and cons of each approach.

I have no experience with Elastic Beanstalk (EB), but I have experience with EC2. I see that you can SSH into an instance and poke around. So, what I suggest further below is based on

- above-stated experiences and on
- the more or less obvious boundary conditions regarding Beanstalk and on
- your application scenario, described in another question here on SO and on
- the fact that you just want to get things running, quickly

**My suggestion:** start off with not building these things yourself. Do not use pip. If possible, try to use the package manager of the Linux distribution in place and let it handle the installation of *everything required* for you, with a single command (e.g. `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib`).

Disadvantages:

- possibly old package versions, depending on the Linux distro in use
- non-optimized builds (e.g. not built against e.g. Intel MKL or not leveraging OpenMP features or not using special instruction sets)

Advantages:

- it quickly downloads, because packages are most likely cached near your machine
- it quickly installs (these packages are pre-built, no compilation involved)
- **it just works**

So, I hope you can just use aptitude or rpm or whatever on these machines and inherit the *great* work that the distribution package maintainers do for you, behind the scenes.

Once you are confident in your application and identified some bottleneck or issue, you might have reason to use a *newer* version of numpy/matplotlib/... or you might have reason to have a *faster* version of these, by creating an optimized build.

### Edit: EB-related details of outlined approach

In the meantime we have learned that EB by default runs [Amazon Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Machine_Image#Amazon_Linux_AMI) which is based on Red Hat Enterprise Linux. Likewise, it uses `yum` as package manager and packages are in RPM format.

Amazon provides documentation about available packages. In Amazon Linux 2014.09, these packages are available: http://aws.amazon.com/de/amazon-linux-ami/2014.09-packages/

In this list we find

- numpy-1.7.2
- python-matplotlib-0.99.1.2

This version of matplotlib is very old, according to the [changelog](http://matplotlib.org/_static/CHANGELOG) it is from September 2009: "2009-09-21 Tagged for release 0.99.1".

I did not anticipate it to be *so* old, but still, it might be sufficient for your needs. So we proceed with our plan (but I'd understand if that's a blocker).

Now, we [have learned](http://www.zezuladp.com/2014/10/scaling-numpy-and-scipy-with-django-and.html) that system Python and EB Python are isolated from each other. That does not mean that EB Python cannot access system Python site packages. We just need it to tell so. A simple and clean method is to set up a proper directory structure with the packages that should be accessible to EB Python, and to communicate this directory to EB Python via `sys.path`.

Clearly, we need to customize the bootstrapping phase of EB containers. The available tools are documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html

Obviously, we want to make use of the `packages` approach, and tell EB to install the `numpy` and `python-matplotlib` packages via yum. So the corresponding config file section should contain:

```
 packages:  
  yum:  
   numpy: []  
   python-matplotlib: []
```

Explicitly mentioning `numpy` might not be necessary, it likely is a dependency of python-matplotlib.

Also, we need to make use of the `commands` section:

> You can use the commands key to execute commands on the EC2 instance.
>   The commands are processed in alphabetical order by name, and they run
>   before the application and web server are set up and the application
>   version file is extracted.

The following three commands create above-mentioned directory, and set up symbolic links to the numpy/mpl installation paths (these paths hopefully are available in the moment these commands become executed):

```
commands:
  00-create-dir:
    command: "mkdir -p /opt/py26-selected-site-packages"
  01-link-numpy:
    command: "ln -s /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy /opt/py26-selected-site-packages/numpy"
  02-link-mpl:
    command: "ln -s /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib /opt/py26-selected-site-packages/matplotlib"
```

Two uncertainties: the AWS docs to not clarify that `packages` are processed before `commands` are executed. You have to try. It it does not work, use `container_commands`. Secondly, it is just an educated guess that `/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib` is available after installing python-matplotlib. It should be installed to this place, but it may end up somewhere else. Needs to be tested. Numpy should end up where specified as inferred from [this](http://www.zezuladp.com/2014/10/scaling-numpy-and-scipy-with-django-and.html) article.

[UPDATE FROM SEB]
AWS documentation says "The cfn-init helper script processes these configuration sections in the following order: packages, groups, users, sources, files, commands, and then services."
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html

So, your approach is safe
[/UPDATE]

The crucial step, as pointed out in the comments to this answer, is to tell your Python app where to look for packages. Direct modification of `sys.path` *before* attempting to import is a reliable method to take control of this. The following code adds our special directory to the selection of directories in which Python looks out for packages, and then attempts to import matplotlib:

```
sys.path.append("/opt/py26-selected-site-packages")
from matplotlib import pyplot
```

The order in `sys.path` defines priorities, so in case there is any other matplotlib or numpy package available in one of the other directories, it might be a better idea to

```
sys.path.insert(0, "/opt/py26-selected-site-packages")
```

However, this should not be necessary if our whole approach was well thought-through.

Comment: Does this work on AWS? Mostly (as stated) I'm interested in getting the simple SSH+PIP approach working (since it's the sanctioned approach; and can be applied to all packages and speed deployment time in general).

Comment: "Does it work on AWS?" I think so, it depends on which Linux distribution is actually running. "it's the sanctioned approach": irrelevant criterion, in the other thread you linked to people were also deviating from this -- it's more important to find a simple, working solution. "can be applied to all packages": aptitude can likely get almost  all of them,too. if you require small special packages that your distro's repo does not contain, retrieving simple packages via pip is good! "speed deployment time": *no*, compilation (e.g. building numpy) takes a huge amount of time.

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning. Have you tried this on AWS? That's the context of he question — getting this working reliably on AWS given all it's peculiarities.

Comment: A Linux VM on EC2 behaves like any other Linux system. And yes, I have tried this on EC2. I just do not know which kind of Linux VM you are running via Elastic Beanstalk (it entirely depends on the Linux distro whether the packages you need are in the repo or not). That is why you need to test my proposal. If it works: great -- simple and reliable method. If it doesn't, another solution must be looked out for. So, SSH into your virtual machine, obtain superuser privileges and use the distro's package manager to install matplotlib to system python. This test should not take more than 5 minutes.

Comment: I'll give it a try next round.

Comment: Thanks to Sébastien's input you now know that there is a package available for your distro. So, go for installing `python-matplotlib.x86_64` via yum, and leverage the automatic deployment configuration, if possible! At least it is worth a try, and quite likely this is sufficient, and you do not require a cutting edge version of matplotlib.

Comment: As near as I can tell, neither of these answers works. The package manager (`yum`) does not put Matplotlib (or for that matter `Numpy` or `SciPy`; and perhaps all packages?) [in a place that is accessible to EB](http://www.zezuladp.com/2014/10/scaling-numpy-and-scipy-with-django-and.html) (the EB virtualenv, that is). For example, they do not appear in `pip list`. Instead they are all in `/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages` which is not (and should not be) on `sys.path`.

Comment: Do not worry, it is straight-forward and okay to work around this limitation (In the article you linked to they also did). I find it much cleaner to manually extend `sys.path` before importing. No need to copy files around, that is a dirty solution (in the article). That is, either adjust the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or, within your Python application, modify `sys.path` accordingly *before* importing numpy/scipy/matplotlib. The latter is a minimal-invasive solution. The goal is to *force* your Python interpreter session to *find* and *use* the system-provided numpy & mpl packages.

Comment: That makes sense (esp. extending the path in the app, which really contains any damage). But — dumb question — what do I add to the path? I clearly don't want to add all of `/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages` (do I?); I just want the specific paths to Matplotlib, etc.; what are those paths?

Comment: Perhaps I could `mkdir my_yumed_packages` in my container commands, move or copy the packages there, and then add that directory to my path. That would keep things nicely isolated. If that approach makes sense; where's the idiomatic place to put such an additional "site-packages" like directory on AWS-EB/

Comment: Very valid point, to not "activate" *all* of the packages in `python2.6/site-packages`! I remember what I have once done: create a directory somewhere, e.g. `/opt/py26-selected-packages`, and then create symlinks(!) in that directory (no moving files around!): Example: `/opt/py26-selected-packages/numpy`, pointing to `/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/numpy` . Then append: `sys.path.append('/opt/py26-selected-packages')`. Add as many symlinks to the directory as you wish, it gives you fine-grained control over which packages you want to make accessible.

Comment: And then I can just add a container command: `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/opt/science-stack-packages"`?

Comment: This *should* work, but it may be that your environment is changed again before your Python app becomes invoked. So, you can try this, but I may not reliably work. For works for sure is the `sys.path` modification *in* your app, right before import. Literally **nothing** can interfere with that. Edit: and yes, your proposed solution and mine are the same, except for the symlink story. I really recommend creating symlinks, for simplicity and performance. Also, your proposed `/opt/science-stack-packages` looks okay to me :). Edit2: remember, the order of items in `sys.path` is important.

Comment: That sounds right. Can you update the answer with these improvements? I think we have a solution. A sample set of container commands for linking etc. (esp.  to get the sequence right an show how and what to link to) would be great! (I assume the `mkdir` container command fails gracefully if the directory is already present?

Comment: Updated the answer and included references for what was found out so far.

Comment: Wow, those are **old** versions; that could easily be a deal breaker. I wonder why AWS is setup this way (why so old; why 2.6). On Heroku, this all happens effortlessly.

Comment: This is a very common topic. It's the way it is because reliability and maintainability is more important than richness in features. For this reason, Amazon Linux inherits from RHEL, who support their releases for a long time. Also, mpl clearly is not the most important package from RHEL's point of view, so they do not take care of merging in newer upstream releases.  Numpy 1.7.2 should not be a problem for you. MPL 0.99 could be, but you have to try first. If it doesn't fit, then there is the option to use mpl RPMs from other distros, such as Fedora. Let's see.

Comment: Note that `ln -s` should be `ln -sf`, I think.

Comment: Also nothing imports, instead I get segmentation faults and `File "/opt/science-site packages/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/numpy/__init__.py", line 122, in <module> from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config` (over and over, getting longer (with an additional  `.../numpy/...` each time).

Comment: `--force` (`-f`) is never good, and surely not needed here. You create the link only *once*, and the "link name"  (e.g. `/opt/py26-selected-site-packages/numpy`) MUST not exist beforehand. Looks like you have executed things multiple times, and somehow created a file system loop with the links.

Comment: It happens even if I remove everything and start fresh. Even if I go through the steps manually over SSH. I'll clean up and try again. As for `-f`, it seems to be necessary. If I've deployed before and the file is already there, the deployment aborts.

Comment: Believe me: in the moment `ln -s` errors out, you have done something wrong which should not be fixed via --force. Why would `/opt/py26-selected-site-packages/numpy` already exist if you didn't create it before? And if you created it before, it's fine and no need to re-create. And if you created it before *wrongly*, then remove it, yes, and bring the correct link into place.

Comment: Yes, no need to recreate; but the deployment fails if its there.

Comment: Probably trivial to resolve, but requires looking into some log files after SSHing into the instance. Move to chat or do you think you manage yourself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69463/discussion-between-raxacoricofallapatorius-and-jan-philip-gehrcke).

Comment: Note
The cfn-init helper script processes these configuration sections in the following order: packages, groups, users, sources, files, commands, and then services. If you require a different order, separate your sections into different config keys, and then use a configset that specifies the order in which the config keys should be processed.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Jan-Philip Answer :

AWS Elastic Beanstalk is using Amazon Linux distribution (except for .Net environments).  Amazon Linux uses the `yum` package manager.  MatPlotLib is available in Amazon's software repository.

```
[ec2-user@ip-1-1-1-174 ~]$ yum list | grep matplot
python-matplotlib.x86_64            0.99.1.2-1.6.amzn1              amzn-main
```

If this version is the one you need for your application, I would try to simply modify your `.ebextensions/software.config` file and to add the package to the yum section of it:

```
packages:
  yum:
    python-matplotlib: [] 
    python-devel: []
    atlas-sse3-devel: []
    lapack-devel: []
    libpng-devel: []
    freetype-devel: []
    zlib-devel: []
```

**A last note about AWS Elastic BeansTalk and SSH.**

While Amazon gives you the possibility to SSH to your Elastic Beanstalk instances, you should use this possibility only for debugging purposes, to understand why your app failed or is not installing as suggested.

Other than that, your deployment must be 100% automatic.  When Elastic Beanstalk (Auto Scaling to be precise) will scale out your infrastructure (add more instances) or scale it in (terminate instances) depending on your application workload, all your manual configuration will be lost.

Best practices is to not install SSH keys on your production environment, it further reduces the surface of attacks.

Comment: Nice, thanks for filling my EB-related knowledge gaps, these answers really go well together :-).

Comment: Good catch; that was going the be my follow on — whether SSH (or any manual configuration) would really work on EB given the fact that environments can be terminated or instantiated automatically (for a variety of reasons).

Comment: One question remains though: why can't I get PIP to work in SSH?

Comment: And another: it looks like [things may not be this simple after all](http://www.zezuladp.com/2014/10/scaling-numpy-and-scipy-with-django-and.html). Will the above be sufficient form my EB application; or will I also need to do the other things (pointing to `site-packages`, etc.) described in this post if I want the `yum` approach to work?

Comment: As near as I can tell, neither of these answers works. The package manager (`yum`) does not put Matplotlib (or for that matter `Numpy` or `SciPy`; and perhaps all packages?) [in a place that is accessible to EB](http://www.zezuladp.com/2014/10/scaling-numpy-and-scipy-with-django-and.html) (the EB virtualenv, that is). For example, they do not appear in `pip list`. Instead they are all in `/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages` which is not (and should not be) on `sys.path`.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late to this question, but as AWS and a lot of the cloud service providers are moving into Docker and taking into consideration that you haven't specified the platform . I have a fast solution to your question:

1. Use the generic docker platform.
2. I created some images with Python, Numpy, Scipy and Matplotlib preinstalled, so you can directly pull and start using them with one line of code.

Python 2.7(This one also has the versions that you were specifying for numpy and matplotlib)

```
sudo docker pull chuseuiti/pynuscimat2.7
```

Python 3.4

```
sudo docker pull chuseuiti/pynusci
```

However you can create your own image or modify existing images.

In case you want to automate your instances, you can pass a Dockerfile to AWS with the definition of your image.

***Tip, in case you don't know about docker:***

It is need to login before been able to pull:

```
sudo docker login
```

After pulling the image, you can generate and work in a container created from an image with the next code:

```
 sudo docker run -i -t chuseuiti/pynuscimat2.7 bash
```

PS. At least with the free tier AWS is always complaining about running out of time with scipy and matplotlib, it takes too much time to install them, that is why I use this option.